# How to serialise control + code in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, custom-controls

I have a canvas which contains several userControls, which in it's turn contains other objects.
I want to serialise the canvas and preserve all databindings and whole visual tree (not all objects can be described in xaml).

I thought creating a custom control which extends canvas and adds ability to serialise will solve this problem.

So the question is: is it a right approach? If not, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that your UI is just a way to show the **state** of your presenter. If you`re using [Presentation Mode](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) or [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) , you can just serialize your presenter. It will solve all your problems

Comment: The problem that you can for instance serialise attached propeties, DP etc. as the don't implement ISerializable interface.

Comment: well, it is a really bad practice to use DP in presenters. In this case, you should make some additional features to maintain multithreading in your application (I'm talking about interaction with UI). Just one example why I can't recommend to use DP in presenters...

Answer (score 0):

I found one work around. That is to put the details of non-seriazable Objects into dictionary or other data structure and serialise it and later retrieve it there when de-serialising the object.

However this doesn't sound very right to me :/ Also had I thought to use both XamlWriter and serialisation to serialise controls, but again I don't think it is the best approach.